# Choosing proper data type in OpenAPI

Tags: yaml, swagger, openapi

Could someone recommend what schema to choose in YAML file for API, if the expected response is the following:

```
"items": [{
        "garden": [{
                "tree": "pine",
                "height": "33"
            }, {
                "height": "33",
                "age": "200"
            }
        ]
    }
],
```

I was thinking about

- list (items)

  - object (garden)

    - list (list of objects)

      - object (pairs - height+age)

I am confused, because property height may appear a lot of times in the list together with different params.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "object (pairs - height+age)"? Do you mean the `garden` property should be an array of objects, each of which has a pair of properties named `height` and `age`? Where does the `tree` property fit into that? Or do you mean the `garden` property should always be an array with exactly two items? Please edit your question to be as specific as possible.

Comment: I also don't understand. That's my task as aa student - create an API in swagger that returns such response in case of success. That's to confusing (because I don't understand should I take array or object) and I decided to ask help here